# asp.net website builds fine but publish gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on asp.net website using ablecommerce asp.net CMS. I am trying to build the website and it works. but when I try to publish the website locally to deploy it on IIS, I start getting errors that this page is not available etc. I see that the page not found errors are actually located in some dll and reference is added.

Errors are like this:

```
Error   5   The type or namespace name 'admin_orders_create_creditcardpaymentform_ascx' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  \Final Code\WebSite\Admin\Orders\Create\CreateOrder4.aspx.cs
```

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: Can you check if your local IIS is running ? also try to place a .html file and .aspx file in the same folder and see if you were able to access those files.

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet I am trying to publish using Visual studio 2010 by clicking publish website from buil menu. IIS is running as well. Publish fails with errors and I get nothing in destination folder.

Comment: post the exact error, that would help

Comment: Is the IIS local / a separate machine? if separate check that you have installed the asp.net and have run the command ' aspnet_regiis -i ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet Please check updated question with error.

Comment: CTRL + F and search for admin_orders_create_creditcardpaymentform_ascx and see the references and why the build is not happening

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet here is it located: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\8296$App_Web_myjo53jx.dll$v4.0.30319$NoDynamic\ASP.admin_orders_create_creditcardpaymentform_ascx.cs

Comment: @MatthewZielonka.co.uk It has nothing to do with IIS as I am publishing using Visual studio on my local system ... I am precompiling website.

Comment: Well the problem is admin_orders_create_creditcardpaymentform_ascx class has not been generated. you might need to work on why that particular file(user control) alone is not generated.

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet What I need to do in this case ?

Comment: i would suggest you to see if for any reason the  class admin_orders_create_creditcardpaymentform_ascx is not generated

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `bin folder` from the project and then try to publish the project.

Answer (score 0):

Close the project, delete temp files then try again and publish code, If this does not work then do check do you have website.publishprog file, If you have then delete that file and then again try to publish website.

Answer (score -1):

if you use routing(i think there are also cms) and not route new page. first you close the precompiled mode check it,If the error persists check routing settings.